Existence of a line wich contain $c|A|$ points
I'm having trobules solving a couple of problems related to dicrete geometry.
Problem 1. Prove that there is a constant $c>0$ that satisfy the following property. For every $A$ non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the set of generated planes
$$S=\left \lbrace \sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_ia_i: \sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_i=1, \lambda_1, \lambda_2,\lambda_3\in \mathbb{R}, \operatorname{dim}\left( \operatorname{Aff}(a_1,a_2,a_3)\right)=2 \right\rbrace$$ with $a_1,a_2,a_3\in A$ have size at most $|A|$, where
$$\operatorname{Aff}(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_ia_i: \sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_i=1, \lambda_1, \lambda_2,\lambda_3\in \mathbb{R}   \right \rbrace$$
. Then exists a line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $|L\cap A|\geq c|A|$.
The idea of my proof is the following.We start by contradiction. Assume the statment is false for every $c>0$. Thus, we have that every line intersects $A$ in at most $c|A|$ points. Write $S=\lbrace \operatorname{Aff}(a_1,a_2,a_3): a_1,a_2,a_3 \in A, \operatorname{dim}\left( \operatorname{Aff}(a_1,a_2,a_3)\right)=2 \rbrace$ the set of all planes generated by $A$. Since $S$ is non empty, we have the set $K=\lbrace L\in \mathbb{R}^3: |L\cap A|\neq \emptyset\rbrace$ is non empty. Take $L\in K$ such that $2\leq |L\cap A|<c|A|$ and observe that by the upper bound in $L$ we have thare is at least $(1-c)|A|$ points outside of $L$ and by the lower bound we can label $t_1,t_2$ be the points on $L\cap A$. Thus, for each pair of two points outside of $L$ and one of $t_1$ or $t_2$ we construct a plane, generating at least $\binom{c|A|}{2}2=\Omega(|A|^2)$ planes, contradicting the hypotesis that $|S|<|A|$.
In the same way, I think the following statment can be proved.
Problem 1.2 Prove that there is a constant $c>0$ that satisfy the following property. For every $A$ non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the set of generated planes Aff(a_1,a_2,a_3) with $a_1,a_2,a_3\in A$ have size at most $|A|^2$. Then exists a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $|L\cap A|\geq c|A|$.
But in this case I don't know how I should continue, since I can´t generalize the previous argument.
Any ideas of how I can prove Problem 1.2 or feedback about my given proof of Problem 1?

1/ can you define Aff($a_1, a_2, a_3$)? 2/ In your argument, you seem to be assuming that the planes constructed are distinct. What happens if the points lie on two lines, $L$ and $I$? How many planes will we get?

$\operatorname{Aff}(a_1,a_2,a_3)=\lbrace \lambda_1a_1+\lambda_2a_2+\lambda_3a_3: \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=1, \lambda_1, \lambda_2,\lambda_3\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$

Please edit that detail in. And what if you have 3 points collinear with the origin? Is a line also considered an affine plane?

By the previous definition can be deduced the following:  if $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are collinear, their affine hul is the line that contain the three points

Note that you didn't say "affine hull". The problem merely stated "set of generated planes". I do not consider a line as a plane.

Ohh, sorry, it's a mistake, I refer  triplets $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in A$ such that $\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{Aff}((a_1,a_2,a_3))=2$

Problem 1 is not true, and hence Problem 2 is not true.
Consider the set of $n^2$ points $ (i, j, 0)$ where $ 1 \leq i, j \leq n$.
Observe that the set of generated planes is just the x-y plane, so $|S| = 1 \leq n^2 = |A|$.
However, any line has at most $ n$ points on it. (Why?)
So any $c$ must satisfy $ c \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Thus, there is no $c >0$ where we can guarantee there is a line that intersects $cn^2$ points.
Note

In the comments, OP says that the generated planes needed to have dimension 2, and that 3 collinear points through the origin do not generate a line as a plane.
This counter example arose by questioning why OP's constructed planes must be distinct, especially if the points only lie on 2 lines. With 2 lines, we still have a line with $\geq 0.5|A|$ points, so we modify the example to make all lines have $\leq \frac{1}{n} |A| $ points.


That's an interesting reflection, in this case, what hypotesis are needed in order to prove a similar statment?

@AlanJr Not immediately obvious to me. At the very least, to avoid this scenario, we'd want the set of points to not lie on a single plane.

Thanks a lot for your clarification, I'm new in this area and the majority of the problems seems hard to me.

Ând what if we permit lines be planes, it is, do you believe is  possible have the conclusion if we request $|S|<|A|$ where we admit a line throught  three colinear points as a plane ?
